# How to construct a good PRF from a block cipher?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

We want to explicitly construct a *good* (as tentatively defined below) Pseudo-Random Function $F$ with $b$-bit input and output, from (preferably just) *one* Pseudo-Random Permutation $E$ of $b$-bit, as instantiated in practice by TDEA for $b=64$ or AES-256 for $b=128$, and *one* fixed random secret key.

I tentatively define a *good* PRF to be one indistinguishable (with small constant advantage) from a random function, assuming $2^{b(1-\epsilon)}$ queries to an oracle implementing our construction of $F$ from $E$, and delegating invocations of $E$ (edit: and in addition of $E^{-1}$ if that helps) to a random oracle for that. Fix this definition as necessary (Update: I'm told by the answers that for $\epsilon<1/2$, this is roughly what's called a *PRF with beyond the birthday bound security*).

Are there simple constructions of $F$ from $E$ with a security argument?

$F(x)=E(x)$ is squarely unfit: it can be distinguished from a random function by detecting collisions after $2^{b/2}$ distinct queries, which happens with sizable probability for a random function but not for a random permutation. That can even be done with constant memory, using [Floyd's cycle finding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare). A distinguisher can also be built against $F(x)=E(x)\oplus x$.

Right now I fail to find a distinguisher for $F(x)=E(E(x)\oplus x)$, but that's not even a weak security argument. Update: If the security of that is unprovable, I'm still interested by a distinguishing attack, in order to get a feeling of how insecure in practice that could be.

Comment: Is the construction of $F$ allowed to use $E^{-1}$? $\:$ (I can't think of a way to do it in either case, but that might help.)

Comment: @Ricky Demer: I amended the definition to allow that. I'm eager to see how that makes a difference.

Comment: Just curious, what is your distinguisher for your first proposal ?

Comment: @Alexandre Yamajako: (fixed) for $F(x)=E(x)$, in the game of distinguishing $F$ from a random function: set $x=y=0$; repeat $⌊2^{b/2}/3⌋$ times: set $x=F(F(x))$, if $x=y$ say "random" and stop, else set $y=F(y)$, if $x=y$ say "random" and stop; say "non-random" with odds 51%, else say "random". For $F(x)=E(x)⊕x$, apply the same distinguisher to $G$ defined by $G(x)=F(x)⊕x$ instead of $F$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with David Cash that what you are looking for is a construction of a PRF with "beyond the birthday bound" security.  There has been a variety of work on this topic.

Stefan Lucks analyzes several simple constructions:

- SUM$^2$: Here $F_{K,K'}(x) = E_K(x) \oplus E_{K'}(x)$.  This has security for up to about $2^{2b/3}$ queries, which is better than the trivial construction.
- SUM$^d$: This is the obvious generalization: $F_{K_1,\dots,K_d}(x) = E_{K_1}(x) \oplus \dots \oplus E_{K_d}(x)$.  This has security up to about $2^{db/(d+1)}$ queries.
- TWIN$^2$: Here $F_K(x) = E_K(x||0) \oplus E_K(x||1)$ (the same construction as David Cash mentions).  This has security for up to about $2^{2b/3}$ queries.
- TWIN$^d$: Here $F_K(x) = E_K(dx+0) \oplus E_K(dx+1) \oplus \dots \oplus E_K(dx+d-1)$, where we consider $0 \le x <2^b/d$.  This has security up to about $2^{db/(d+1)}$ queries.

Here is the paper:

- [The Sum of PRPs is a Secure PRF](http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/People/Lucks/papers/SumOfPRP.neu.pdf), Stefan Lucks.  Eurocrypt 2000.

I think there is still more work out there on this topic.

Comment: Interestingly, none of these constructions beat the birthday bound while using a single key and working over the same domain.

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is often called a construction of a PRF with "beyond the birthday bound security," and you can probably find some constructions by searching on variants of that term.

For concreteness, this [paper by Iwata](https://doi.org/10.1007/11799313_20) (alternate [link](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/data/paper.php?pubkey=3243)) almost gives a solution to your problem: The only deficiencies are that the resulting $F$ has inputs one bit narrower than $E$, and it does not achieve your definition of security for every $\varepsilon > 0$.  Specializing that construction down to your setting, and using your notation, it defines $F(x)$ for $x\in\{0,1\}^{b-1}$ as $$F(x) = E(x\|0)\oplus E(x\|1),$$
where $\|$ denotes concatenation.  Its proof applies for a number queries well beyond $2^{b/2}$, which is obviously non-trivially better than the direct $F(x) = E(x)$ construction.

Answer (score 5):

I think this paper may help:

M. Bellare, T. Krovetz and P. Rogaway (1998),
["Luby-Rackoff backwards: Increasing security by making block ciphers non-invertible"](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/p2f-abstract.html), *Advances in Cryptology - EUROCRYPT '98*, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, Vol. 1403.

> "**Abstract:** We argue that the invertibility of a block cipher can reduce the security of schemes that use it, and a better starting point for scheme design is the non-invertible analog of a block cipher, that is, a pseudorandom function (PRF). Since a block cipher may be viewed as a pseudorandom permutation, we are led to investigate the reverse of the problem studied by Luby and Rackoff, and ask, how can one transform a PRP into a PRF in as security-preserving a way as possible? The solution we propose is "data-dependent re-keying." As an illustrative special case, let $E: \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$ be the block cipher. Then we can construct the PRF $F$ from the PRP $E$ by setting $F(k,x) = E(E(k,x),x)$. We generalize this to allow for arbitrary block and key lengths, and to improve efficiency. We prove strong quantitative bounds on the value of data-dependent re-keying in the Shannon model of an ideal cipher, and take some initial steps towards an analysis in the standard model."

[A PDF of the paper is available here.](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/p2f.pdf) (The PDF link on the abstract page is wrong, it leads to the PS version.)

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted.  It looks like the sort of thing that fgrieu is looking for: it is a construction of a PRF with "beyond the birthday bound" security, out of a block cipher.  Its main limitation is that they can only prove good security in the ideal cipher model (which is a much stronger model than assuming that the block cipher is a PRP), but still, it's relevant and a result.

Comment: Perhaps the answer should contain more than just a link, i.e. shortly summarizing the results given by the paper? I didn't downvote though.

Comment: I upvoted, as the construct fits the goal in the title. But it does not fit the more detailed statement, which requires that F is built from _one_ E (in a block-cipher context: no re-keying).